# Variadic compose function?

Tags: haskell, variadic, function-composition, pointfree

I'm trying to write a variadic function composition function. Which is basically the `(.)` except that the second argument function is variadic. This should allow expressions like:

```
map even . zipWith (+)
```

or just

```
map even . zipWith
```

Currently what I've reached works if I add `IncoherentInstances` and requires a non-polymorphic instance for the first argument function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, 
FunctionalDependencies, UndecidableInstances, KindSignatures #-}

class Comp a b c d | c -> d where
    comp :: (a -> b) -> c -> d

instance Comp a b (a :: *) (b :: *) where
    comp f g = f g

instance Comp c d b e => Comp c d (a -> b) (a -> e) where
    comp f g = comp f . g
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: can you explain a bit more what do you mean by "variadic function composition"? maybe add some examples.

Comment: I clarified a little bit in the last edit. Besides that, what's wrong with the two given examples?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Examples are fine. It was not obvious for me that they do not typecheck.

Comment: You may want to look at [Concatenative, Row-Polymorphic Programming in Haskell](https://github.com/leonidas/codeblog/blob/master/2012/2012-02-17-concatenative-haskell.md) and [Playing with Factor's Row Polymorphism in Haskell](https://gist.github.com/1847747) since row polymorphism is specifically useful for composing functions of all arities.

Comment: "Currently what I've reached works if I add IncoherentInstances and requires a non-polymorphic instance for the first argument function." So what is your question, exactly? It might be possible to get around those restrictions, but almost certainly not in plain Haskell 2010.

Comment: @Dan I want the given examples to work. Which means that I should be able to compose any functions without having to give an instance for the possible types of the second argument function. And hopefully without `IncoherentInstances`.

Comment: @is7s, FWIW, anything with "variadic" is not likely to play nice with the rest of the language.  It is doable with typeclass hacks, and fun, but I wouldn't recommend it for "real code".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to type-hack it into working with polymorphic functions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses,
  IncoherentInstances, UndecidableInstances,
  FunctionalDependencies, TypeFamilies,
  NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}


class Comp a b c | a b -> c where
    (...) :: a -> b -> c

instance (a ~ c, r ~ b) => Comp (a -> b) c r where
    f ... g = f g

instance (Comp (a -> b) d r1, r ~ (c -> r1)) => Comp (a -> b) (c -> d) r where
    f ... g = \c -> f ... g c

t1 = map even ... zipWith (+)
t2 = map even ... zipWith
t3 = (+1) ... foldr
```

But I doubt you can avoid `IncoherentInstances`