# Functional composition with multi-valued functions in haskell?

Tags: haskell, pointfree, function-composition

I was wondering if it was possible to do functional composition with functions that take more than one argument. I want to be able to do something like this

```
x = (+3).(*)
```

setting x equal to a function that adds three to the product of two numbers.

Comment: http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656797/variadic-compose-function) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, but they're all somewhat awkward.

```
((+3).) . (*)
≡ fmap (+3) . (*)
≡ curry $ (+3) . uncurry (*)
≡ \l r -> l*r + 3
```

Oh, wait, this was the signature where there's also a compact definition, guess what it's called...

```
((.).(.)) (+3) (*)
```

I'd argue that the lambda solution, being most explicit, is rather the best here.

What helps, and is often done just locally as a one(or two)-liner, is to define this composition as a custom infix:

```
(.:) :: (c->d) -> (a->b->c) -> a->b->d
f .: i = \l r -> f $ i l r
```

Which allows you to write simply `(+3) .: (*)`.

BTW, for the similar `(b->b->c) -> (a->b) -> a->a->c` (precompose the right function to *both* arguments of the infix) there exists [a widely-used standard implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Function.html#v%3aon).

Comment: I like `((.).(.))` the best, mainly because I like to imagine [Frankie Howerd](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankie_Howerd) discovered it

Comment: +1 for fmap (the coolest) and the lambda (the one I'd want in any codebase I was working on!)

Comment: yes - take the lambda or better give the function a name - in all honesty: the other solutions are intelectual pleasing but more or less unreadable (you can rediscover them easily true but I would say unreadable) - things like this gives Haskell it's "arcane ebony-tower" label that discourages so many good developers to look into Haskell

Comment: Is there a common, Englihs-language name for (.).(.)?

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr.: _yes_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout What is that name?

Comment: The ((.).(.)) is just bluffing me, i totally understand (.) but i can't understand ((.).(.)), i thing i am going to use pen and paper to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'd use something like this:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/composition/latest/doc/html/Data-Composition.html

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the B1 or blackbird combinator from [Data.Aviary.Birds](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-aviary/0.2.3/doc/html/Data-Aviary-Birds.html). I think for real work I'd use a lambda though.