# How to use curried functions in Haskell with map?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

Trying to learn how to use folds by redefining prelude functions:

```
import Prelude hiding (sum, product, length, and, or, all, any, filter)
```

So far I've got up to all working, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with all. I'm defining it as follows:

```
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
and = foldr (&&) True

...

all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all = and $ map
```

But this displays an error saying :

```
Probable cause: ‘map’ is applied to too few arguments
```

I've also tried defining it as:

```
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
and = foldr (&&) True

...

all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all f [xs] = and $ map f [xs]
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to call it it says:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Fold             ( Fold.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Fold.
*Fold> all even [0,2,4,6]
*** Exception: Fold.hs:17:1-29: Non-exhaustive patterns in function all
```

which I don't understand since shouldn't [xs] match any list, even an empty one? Why can I curry foldr without including the list but not map? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your last error is because `[xs]` will only match a list with a single element. Just remove the square braces from the parameter and the argument to `map`.

Comment: Downvoter should comment, given neither the answer or question are really that bad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ah thank you that makes sense

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't think this question deserves a downvote either, but that's not my call to make, or yours. People can vote how they like, and there's no obligation to explain why in the comments.

Comment: @amalloy It's good etiquette to explain a downvote though; especially when the OP only has only 8 rep and may be unaware of something wrong they did. Not necessary, no, but certainly helpful to people who aren't familiar with the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up function application with composition. Does this help?

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all fn = and . (map fn)
```

In practise, this is equivalent to your code + the comment from  @Carcigenicate

Comment: Didn't down vote, but I reckon the person who did would've wanted you to explain the `Non-exhaustive patterns in function all` error.

Comment: @Simon H that's great thank you, clearly I need to brush up on composition and application

Comment: Note: you do need to have the `fn` parameter at all: `all = and . map` is fine.

Comment: @Bakuriu See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16888222/625403 for one of the many questions asking why the thing you propose doesn't work.