# Haskell Absolute Difference Using Function Compsition

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I am trying to define a function to find the absolute difference of two numbers, such that both

```
absoluteDifference 2 5
absoluteDifference 5 2
```

return `3`.

Here is my best effort so far:

```
absoluteDifference :: Num a => a -> a -> a
absoluteDifference = abs . (-)
```

In my head, this applies `abs` to the result of subtracting two numbers. However, this gives me the error

```
* Could not deduce (Num (a -> a)) arising from a use of `abs'
    (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
  from the context: Num a
    bound by the type signature for:
               absoluteDifference :: Num a => a -> a -> a
    at C:\Users\Adam\dev\daily-programmer\e311\e311.hs:3:1-42
* In the first argument of `(.)', namely `abs'
  In the expression: abs . (-)
  In an equation for `absoluteDifference':
      absoluteDifference = abs . (-)
```

Which I don't understand. I could trivially implement the function as

```
absoluteDifference a b = abs $ a - b
```

but I want to know how to compose the functions.

Comment: yeah, in these cases, I prefer to use the infix notation rather than point free notation as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The info for `(.)`

```
Prelude> :i (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

shows that it accepts functions with types `a -> b`

but `(-)` has the type

```
Prelude> :i (-)
class Num a where
  ...
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
infixl 6 -
```

so, it is possible to define another composition operator that accepts functions having the above type, and then they can be composed.

```
of' :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
of' f g a b = f (g a b)

abdiff = abs `of'` (-)

abdiff 1 10
9
```

note: as user @david-young points out correctly, `of'` can be more general by specifying the type as below:

```
of' :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d -> a) -> c -> d -> b
of' f g x y = f (g x y)
```

Comment: The type signature of `of'` can be generalized quite a bit further.

Comment: true, but lazily hitting 1 key (i.e. `a`) is very satisfying :P. updating answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

Besides defining a custom operator, as suggested by [Haleemur Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44081548/2751851), one alternative is making the definition less point-free by having a single-argument function as the second argument of `(.)`.

```
absoluteDifference a = abs . (-) a
```

Given how similar are the roles of the two arguments in your function, from a readability point of view it doesn't make much sense to write it in this way (though it might work better in other cases).

Another possibility is making it more point-free (by having a function-modifying function as the first argument of `(-)`):

```
absoluteDifference = (abs .) . (-)
```

While this is a nice parlour trick, this sort of code with `(.)` sections is rather cryptic, and it is generally a good idea to avoid it in "real" code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not an owl operator?

```
(...) = (.) . (.)
absoluteDifference = abs ... (-)
```

Comment: Why not variadic composition? ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656797/variadic-compose-function

Answer (score 1):

Actually your answer is pretty close. All you need is to amend it as follows;

```
absDiff :: Num a => a -> a -> a
absDiff n = abs . (n-)

*Main> absDiff 3 9
6
*Main> absDiff 9 3
6
```